# the code causes a segfault after I called "atoi" function

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I created a function to parse strings look like "NAME:Sebastion | AGE:4 | DATE:8/2/2005", and I was trying to get the year "2005". I wrote a function as the following. a segfault occurs at the line when I call "atoi". The valgrind show me that

```
           Invalid read of size 1
    ==25142==    at 0x5171167: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:298)
    ==25142==    by 0x516DB6F: atoi (atoi.c:27)
    ==25142==    by 0x400AB4: inYear (prelab8.c:115)
    ==25142==    by 0x40094E: main (prelab8.c:46)
    ==25142==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd



int inYear(char* string)
{
      char* word;
      word= strtok(string, "|");
      word= strtok(NULL,"|");
      word= strtok(NULL,"|");
      char * new;
      new = strtok(word,":");
      new= strtok(NULL,"/");
      new= strtok(NULL,"/");
      new= strtok(NULL,"/");
      //printf("%s\n",new);
      int year;
      year= atoi(new); // segfault 
      //printf("%d\n",year);
       if(year!=2005)
       return 0;

      return 1; 
 }
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ypx2LJdIJJag1Zjb). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your debugger?

Comment: That code should work with that string. However, in real life, you should check the return value that you get  from `strtok`. The segfault is caused by passing a `NULL` pointer to `atoi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you're passing in to this function doesn't match what it expects.  By not checking if `strtok` returned `NULL`, you don't account for this possibility and end up pasing a `NULL` pionter to `atoi`, causing  your program to crash.

After **every** call to `strtok`, check if it returns `NULL` and if so handle the error.

Also, don't use C++ keywords such as `new` as variable or function names in C.  It can be confusing to the reader and will cause issues if you attempt to convert from C to C++.

Comment: Last paragraph is irrelevant and IMO misguided. C and C++ are different languages and there's no reason to program in the awful language that is their intersection unless you have to.